# Two drivers, two calculations, one cell

Tags: formulas

I have a trucking business with two drivers.  I receive a `value` ($) for each `load` my business delivers.

I pay a `share` (%) of that `value` to the driver of the `load`.

The `share` for "Driver1" is 25% and the `share` for "Driver2" is 85%.

I am using a dropdown in column B to identify the `driver` of each `load` in column A.

I'm looking for a formula in column M to calculate the `amount` ($) I owe based on the `driver` selected in column B.

**Example:**

|  | A | B | . . . | M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Load Value** | **Driver** |  | **Share of Load** |
| **2** | $953 | Driver1 |  |  |
| **3** | $2,828 | Driver2 |  |  |
| **4** | $1,369 | Driver1 |  |  |
| **5** | $1,387 | Driver1 |  |  |
| **6** | $809 | Driver2 |  |  |
| **7** | $2,980 | Driver1 |  |  |
| **8** | $1,826 | Driver2 |  |  |

Comment: What web app are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### IF Function

Returns one value if a logical expression is TRUE and another if it is FALSE.
**Syntax:** `IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)`

##### Formula

```
=IF(B2="Driver1",A2*25%,
 IF(B2="Driver2",A2*85%,""))
```

The formula above uses what is referred to as "nested" IF functions.  The second IF function is used as the ***value_if_false*** for the first IF function. The second IF function has a NULL value as its own ***value_if_false***.  In this way, there are three possible outcomes to the formula:   `A2*25%`   *or*   `A2*85%`   *or*   `""`  *(NULL)*

| logical_expression | value_if_true | value_if_false |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `B2="Driver1"` | `A2*25%` | `IF(B2="Driver2",A2*85%,"")` |
| `B2="Driver2"` | `A2*85%` | `""` |

[image]
**<sup><sub>Example where `driver` not specified</sub></sup>**

[image]

---

##### Specifying Microsoft  Excel vs Google Sheets

Further to [Laurel's comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/169610/two-drivers-two-calculations-one-cell#comment156864_169610), it is important to specify in  your question if it relates to Microsoft Excel or Google Sheets.  You can additionally use `[microsoft-excel]` or `[google-sheets]` [tags](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags).

There is a lot of overlap in functionality between the two apps but there are many differences in syntax for the same functions, and many functions exist only in one or the other.  This can create unforeseen outcomes and also break formulas.

Here is an example of differences in output from the IF function in Excel vs. Sheets.  In **2a** you note that Sheets can return a *truly* blank cell by omitting a value.  Excel will return a `0` for the same formula, and using the COUNTA function I show that only Sheets in **2a** returns a *truly* BLANK value.  The cells in **3a** that contain NULL values *appear* BLANK but are seen by COUNTA as containing a value (3b).

| Ref# | Formula | Excel Output | Sheets Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1a** | `=IF(1=2,TRUE)` | `FALSE` | `FALSE` |
| **1b** | `=COUNTA(IF(1=2,TRUE))` | `1` | `1` |
|  |  |  |  |
| **2a** | `=IF(1=2,TRUE,)` | `0` |  |
| **2b** | `=COUNTA(IF(1=2,TRUE,))` | `1` | `0` |
|  |  |  |  |
| **3a** | `=IF(1=2,TRUE,"")` |  |  |
| **3b** | `=COUNTA(IF(1=2,TRUE,""))` | `1` | `1` |